# when condition in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In declarative pipeline we have when condition like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            when {
                changeset 'service1\**'
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Building'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's any ways to do some thing in scripted pipeline?

Comment: No duplicates. I'm talking about 'changeset' in when

Answer (score 3):

You could check for files matching a certain pattern somehow like this (not tested)

Create a function to check for changes in the desired directory...

```
@NonCPS
boolean isMyDirChanged() {
  for (changeLogSet in currentBuild.changeSets) { 
    for (entry in changeLogSet.getItems()) { // for each commit in the detected changes
      for (file in entry.getAffectedFiles()) {
        if (file.getPath() ==~ /^service1/) {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

... and then use the function for determining if some code should be executed

```
if (isMyDirChanged()) {
  print ('Building')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ill will try. Can i ask some question? How i can check each 'service' from declared map?

Like:
```
def map = [
  "SVC1" : "/service1",
  "SVC2" : "/service2",
  "SVC3" : "/service3"
]
```

Comment: Try the following as condition to check if the file path is contained in any of the map´s values: map.any{key, value -> file.getPath() ==~ value}

Comment: Thanks! It's work. But i used =~ (the find operator) instead of ==~ (the match operator).

Comment: Great! Please do consider marking your question as answered. Thank you

Comment: Another question.
Is any way to get changes from git instead of changes in worspace folder?